# Set value to variable in argparse if option passed in

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-y', '--y-option', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

y_option = "enable_y" if args.y_option else ''
print(y_option)
```

if `-y` or `--y-option` is passed in, I want to set variable `y_option` to `enable_y` else an empty string, I believe this should be possible with argparse so the `y_option = ...` line is not needed? I couldn't figure it out. I cannot use default as it will set default value even if `-y` is not passed in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
parser.add_argument('-y', '--y-option', action='store_const', const='enable_y', default='')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action